# system.IO.File.Exists() in .RDLCs always returns false

Tags: vb.net, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to determine if a file exists by using the line:

=system.IO.File.Exists("C:\camera.log")

I know for a fact the file exists. But no matter how I phrase the line of code, it always returns false. I've changed the permissions in RSPreviewPolicy.config and rssrvpolicy.config to no effect. I'm running the report locally, so permissions shouldn't come into it.

Please let me know if I can provide any further information.

UPDATE: The line works fine in a regular Console Application. So far as I know, this problem is unique to .rdlc reports.

UPDATE 2: It also works on previewed SSRS reports. But I have verified it also doesn't work on another .RDLC report.

Comment: Do you need to escape your path string?  In C# backslash is an escape character.  Try: @"C:\camera.log".  The ampersand tells .Net not to escape the string.

Comment: sadly, @ is not valid VB syntax. Can you try it somewhere other than C:\

Comment: Still didn't work. I tried my D:\ and E:\ drive and it still can't find the files.